# Can't programmatically bind NSImageView in view-based NSTablveView cellView

Tags: nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I have a view-based NSTableView which is a single column with a custom CellView containing about a dozen text fields and a single NSImageView.

```
-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    ComboTableCellView* view = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:[tableColumn identifier] owner:nil];

    // I bind the text fields with:

    [[view nameView] bind:NSValueBinding toObject:view withKeyPath:@"objectValue.name" options:nil];

    // I bind the NSImageView with:

    NSMutableDictionary* statusOptions = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0] autorelease];
    [options setObject:kStatusIconTransformerName forKey:NSValueTransformerNameBindingOption];
    [[view statusView] bind:NSValueBinding toObject:view withKeyPath:@"objectValue.status" options:statusOptions];

    return (view);
}
```

My transformer takes "status" which is an NSNumber and returns an NSImage because status will be a number from 1 to 4. This works in a cell based NSTableView with an NSImage column.

However, in my view-based NSTableView I get:

Cannot remove an observer (NSAutounbinderObservance 0x600000028ac0) for the key path "objectValue.status" from (ComboTableCellView 0x6180001e3e00), most likely because the value for the key "objectValue" has changed without an appropriate KVO notification being sent. Check the KVO-compliance of the ComboTableCellView class.

How can I correctly bind an NSImageView that is within a reuseable view used as the row/cellview in a view-based NStableView?

Comment: Since you're using a custom class for the cell view, show how it implements the `objectValue` property. If it inherits the property from its superclass, does it override any aspect of it? Do you manually unbind those bindings anywhere, like `-tableView:didRemoveRowView:forRow:`? Show that. Since you're not manually creating the cell view and relying on `-makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` to make one, does that mean it comes from a NIB? If so, why can't the binding be set up there?

Comment: I am not doing anything at all with objectValue. I gather that it is provided by the superclass and I am not unbinding anything either. The bindings are done in code because the user can change some of the fields that are shown.

Comment: In awakeFromNib I have bound the table view's @"content" to the array controller's @"arrangedObjects" as well as @"selectionIndexes" to @"selectionIndexes" and @"sortDescriptors" to @"sortDescriptors". I just don't understand why the text field bindings work but the NSImageView does not. If I bind a text field to @"objectValue.status" without the transformer, it works and shows the right status number. If I enable the transformer, it does get called and is returning an NSImage.

Comment: If I set this up in IB it works. So why isn't it working when I do it from code?

Comment: Do you unbind the views in `prepareForReuse`?

Comment: No. Should I be doing that?